# How do i write a "events per second" PerformanceCounter?

Tags: c#

I'm currently using the PeformanceCounter Increment method. If I call this on every event will the PeformanceCounter framework calc the events per second? Or I have have to write the code to do this? If so does anyone have any examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define multiple counters: number of operations, average time per operation and average time per operation base. Here's a [nice article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx) that should help you get started.